# Problem with API-call with passport-spotify and spotify-web-api-node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a async function that use authorization with Spotify to get a users top artist and tracks and then put it into a database. I have restructured my DB functions to support async calls the latest days, but now my API call wont work anymore. I get a error message due to that the accessKey I supply the api-call with isn't given a value when the code reach that point, thus I've deducted that the issue is a matter of my code not playing as needed in terms of asynchronicity (try saying that word 10 times after another...).

I'm pretty new to this async way of thinking about the code and was hoping you could help me structure the code so that it plays out as needed.

Currently the code stops at the following line, due to the async issues I've described above, where accessToken has the value of "undefined".

> spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);

```
/* Function for retrieving data from spotify passport */
module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(
        new SpotifyStrategy(
          {
            clientID: 'CLIENT ID',
            clientSecret: 'CLIENT SECRET',
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8888/auth/spotify/callback',
            passReqToCallback: true
          },
          async (accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) => {
            
            
            /* Put the incoming data in an object "aUser" */
            const aUser = Object.create(user);
            aUser.username = profile.username;
            aUser.displayName = profile.displayName;
            aUser.profilePicture = profile.photos[0];
            aUser.email = profile._json.email;
            
            /* RUN ALL CODE BELOW THIS IN userHandler Async function (to keep track of
              user_id throughout all coming calls). This will first check if user
              is in db, if not add it, and return it's user_id for coming calls, if
              it is in db, it will simply return it's user_id to be used in coming
              calls */
              
              async function checking() {

                /* Check if user is in DB, if not, add. Store user_id in "user" for
                using in other calls */

                let user_id = await checkUser(aUser.username, aUser.displayName, aUser.profilePicture, aUser.email);

                /* Check if artistPreferences OR trackPreferences contain row that
                was created 30 days or longer ago. If true, delete all rows
                in both tables and then run code below. If false, return from function */

                let preferencesStatus = await checkPreferences(user_id);
              
                // If user preferences was older than 30 days and checkPreferences
                // deleted the tables, run the folliwing code:
                if (preferencesStatus === true) {
                 
                    /* SET UP SPOTIFY API CALL TO GET TOP STATS FROM USER */

                    // Initialize spotifyapi object
                    var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();

                    // Set accesstoken for api objct
                    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                
                    /* STEP 1: RETRIEVE TOP ARTISTS FOR CURRENT USER */

                    spotifyApi.getMyTopArtists({ limit: 1 })
                    .then(function(data) {
                        let topArtistsRaw = data.body.items;
                    
                        // Map top artists and key data into a new array
                        let mappedArtists = topArtistsRaw.map(artist => {
                            return {
                            artist: artist.name, 
                            popularity: artist.popularity,
                            url: artist.external_urls.spotify,
                            image: artist.images[0].url
                            }
                        });

                        // Map through each favorite artist of the user
                        mappedArtists.map(artist => {
                            let a_artist = artist.artist;
                            let a_popularity = artist.popularity;
                            let a_url = artist.url;
                            let a_image = artist.image;

                            // Check if artist is in the general artist-table, if not add
                            // Store the artist_id in variable
                            let artist_id = checkArtist(a_artist);
                            console.log(`artist ID NEW: ${artist_id}`);

                            // Add the artist to current users artistPreferences table
                            addArtistPreferences(user_id, artist_id);
                        });
                    });

                    /* STEP 2: RETRIEVE TOP TRACKS FOR CURRENT USER */
                    spotifyApi.getMyTopTracks({ limit:1 })
                    .then(function(data) {
                    
                        let topTracksRaw = data.body.items;

                        // Map key data for each track into new array
                        let mappedTracks = topTracksRaw.map(track => {
                            return {
                            trackname: track.name, 
                            artist: track.artists[0].name,
                            popularity: track.popularity,
                            url: track.external_urls.spotify
                            }
                        });

                        // Check if each track is in the DB, if not add
                        mappedTracks.map(track => {
                            let a_track = track.trackname;
                            let a_artist = track.artist;
                            let a_url = track.url;
                            let a_popularity = track.popularity;
                        
                            // Check if current track is in the collective artist/track DB
                            // Store track_id in variable
                            let track_id = checkTrack(a_track, a_artist);
                
                            // Add the user trackPreferences DB's
                            addTrackPreferences(user_id, track_id, a_artist);
                        });
                    });
                }   
              }  

              checking();

              return done(null, profile);
   
          }         
        )
      );

      // Serialize
      passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
      });
      
      passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
          done(null, user);
      });
}
```

Comment: you can use `await` on all the functions with `.then`, because those functions return a promise

Comment: But how do I make the following call await as well?                     spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);

Comment: `spotifyApi.setAccessToken` is not an async function, so you don't need to await for it, it will be executed sequentially by default.

Comment: You need neither tags in the title (they go in the tags) nor to edit in `[SOLVED]`. We know the question is answered when you accept an answer, as you have done.

Comment: Alright, just trying to improve my questions, I've gained good reputation this latest days but that don't seem to count to my ban...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do some things to make this work:

1. Remove the following line: `passReqToCallback: true` - having this activated gave the wrong type of response to the spotify strategy, so disabling it made it right.
2. I adapted my mapping functions to a async format, like the following:

   ```
                            mappedTracks.map(async track => {
                            let a_track = track.trackname;
                            let a_artist = track.artist;
                            let a_url = track.url;
                            let a_popularity = track.popularity;

                            // Check if current track is in the collective artist/track DB
                            // Store track_id in variable
                            let track_id = await checkTrack(a_track, a_artist);
                            console.log('user_id and track_id: ' + user_id + ' and ' + track_id);


                        // Add the user trackPreferences DB's
                        addTrackPreferences(user_id, track_id, a_artist);
                    });
   ```
3. I also updated the function call with an await statement: `await checking();`